# The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received undefined

Tags: node.js

I have some Node.js code:

```js
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    fs.readFile('demofile1.html', function (err, data) {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
        res.write(data);
        return res.end();
    });
}).listen(8080);
```

and an HTML file:

```html
<html>

<body>
    <h1>My Header</h1>
    <p>My paragraph.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

When I'm trying to display HTML's content to server, there appears an error

> The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received undefined
> at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
> at write_ (node:_http_outgoing:872:11)
> at ServerResponse.write (node:_http_outgoing:831:15)
> at ReadFileContext.callback(C:\Users\ASUS\OneDrive\Máy tính\Nodejs\myfirst.js:6:13
> at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (node:fs:325:13) {
> code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
> }

How can I fix this?

I follow the idea in w3school Node.js

Answer (score 0):

This is one of my code wherein I used asynchronous JS concepts , and hereafter it worked for me

```
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
const url = "mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017";
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const database = "ecomm"
const client = new MongoClient(url);

async function getData() {
try {
  await client.connect();
  const db = client.db(database);
  const collection = db.collection("products");
  const response = await collection.find({}).toArray();
  return response;
} catch (error) {
  console.error("Error:", error);
  throw error;
} finally {
  client.close();
}}

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
try {
  const data = await getData();
  res.send(JSON.stringify(data));
} catch (error) {
  res.status(500).send('Error retrieving data');
}});
```

Comment: And the code given by you works correct in my system :) !